# Error in Hibernate simple example Beginner level

Tags: java, hibernate

In order to learn hibernate, I write two examples for practising. However, both of them have same error as following:

> Failed to create sessionFactory object.java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/transaction/SystemException Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException     at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2248)   at
>   org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2214)   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.(Configuration.java:184)  at
>   com.example.ManageEmployee.main(ManageEmployee.java:17)

Basically, I write POJO first, and using eclipse generates hbm.xml. After than, I write main function to manage the database. I tried twice but got same problem.

Could someone give me advice to solve this problem? Before that, using JDBC builds a project, but that is too complex. So I need to learn hibernate. Thank you.

Supplement(detail in this hibernate example project):

1. My Eclipse project Name: **HibernateExa**
2. **hibernate.cfg.xml**:

   ```
   <session-factory>

       <!-- hibernate dialect -->

       <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.password">hibernateTest</property>

       <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernatetest;</property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.username">hibernater</property>
       <property name="hibernate.default_schema">hibernatetest</property>
       <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

       <!-- Automatic schema creation(begin) -->
       <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
       <!-- Simple memory-only cache -->
       <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider</property>
       <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
       <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

       <!-- mapping files with external dependencies -->
       <mapping resource="com/sample/Person.hbm.xml"/>


   </session-factory>
   ```
3. My POJO is **Person.java**. Using eclipse generates **Person.hbm.xml**.
4. Project contains main function: TestPerson.java

   ```
   public static void main(String [] args){

       Session session = SessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

       session.beginTransaction();

       createPerson(session);
       queryPerson(session);

   }

   public static void createPerson(Session session){
       Person person = new Person();

       person.setName("Jack");
       person.setSurname("Yu");
       person.setAddress("White House");

       session.save(person);
   }

   private static void queryPerson(Session session){
       Query query = session.createQuery("from person");
       List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();
       list = query.list();
       java.util.Iterator<Person> iter = list.iterator();

       while(iter.hasNext()){
           Person person = iter.next();
           System.out.println("Person: \"" + person.getName() + "\", "+ person.getSurname() + "\", "
                   + person.getAddress());
       }

       session.getTransaction().commit();
   }
   ```
5. Here is error info:

   Initial SessionFactory creation failed. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/EntityListeners
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
       at com.sample.SessionFactoryUtil.(SessionFactoryUtil.java:17)
       at com.sample.TestPerson.main(TestPerson.java:14)
   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/EntityListeners
       at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAMetadataProvider.getDefaults(JPAMetadataProvider.java:97)
       at org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.getDefaults(JavaReflectionManager.java:226)
       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1331)
       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1756)
       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1840)
       at com.sample.SessionFactoryUtil.(SessionFactoryUtil.java:13)
       ... 1 more
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.EntityListeners
       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
       ... 7 more

Basically, this example could help me to practise how to using hibernate. Nevertheless, I got problem at the very beginning that create the project.

Hopefully, I could solve this problem soon. Please some advice, Thank you.

Comment: You're missing jta.jar from the project libraries or dependencies in Eclipse. (Or another equivalent jar which contains the missing class.)

Comment: Thanks madth3, I add jta now, but still has this issue.

Comment: If you added JTA correctly you would not have the same exact issue. Please add information about your Eclipse project and how do you execute it.

Comment: Hi madth3, I put more details. Wish we could find problem on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please make sure you have all of this jar files in your lib folder:

```
lib/antlr.jar
lib/cglib.jar
lib/asm.jar
lib/commons-collections.jar
lib/commons-logging.jar
lib/jta.jar
lib/dom4j.jar
lib/log4j.jar
lib/hibernate3.jar
```

Comment: Hi Fahimeh, Thank you for your suggestion. I download the hibernate-4.3.0 and get the require jar file that contains: 
antlr-2.7.7
avro-1.6.3
dom4j-1.6.1
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.2
hibernate-core-4.2.2
jackson-core-asl-1.9.2
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2
javassist-3.15.0-GA
jboss-logging-3.1.0
jta-1.1
lucene-core-3.6.2
paranamer-2.3
slf4j-api-1.6.1
snappy-java-1.0.4.1
       But still has same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is solved! Thanks for everyone's advice.

So I summary the issue and give the solution.

ERROR: Initial SessionFactory creation failed. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. 
some jar files are misssing.

In order to set hibernate project, here is the list for jar files:

[image]

1. Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: person is not mapped [from person]   Because hibernate query is based on Object, from person should be from Person.
2. The correct connection url:

   jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernatetest?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=GBK
3. In DB, the id is INT. However, in Person.hbm.xml I change id type to "long". Thus, the expected result comes out.

Comment: Eric, Does these all jars are include in our hibernate-release5.2.14.Final file or Do we have to dowload them from some where?

Answer (score 1):

Add this dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
   <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
   <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Make a `mvn clean install` and deploy.

Another way:
 *Download this jar*  :   Project -->right click --> build path --> add external jar

Project-->right click -->properties --> deployment assembly --> add --> add from build path entries (add this jar)

Now re build the project.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Place below dependency inside your pom.xml or add persistence-api jar in your classpath.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
   <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```